# Why isn't gmail listed as a recent app when I long-press the Home button?

Tags: email, gmail, app-widgets, recents-screen

This would be helpful at times... I usually just end up pressing home and selecting the gmail widget from there but I've gotten used to long-pressing home to get to recent apps.

Could it be due to the fact that I get to email using the widget? Does it work with the native email client or other email apps?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The recent app list is the recently 'started' app list. Aka you clicked their start icon to start them. The recent app list is not the recently opened application list wich would have been much easier to work with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you haven't opened the application in a while, it will naturally disappear from the list of recent apps.  Try opening it with the widget and then going back to the home screen.  If gmail is once again under you list of recent apps, you just haven't opened it in a while.  If it doesn't appear at all, then the widget you are using doesn't add gmail as a recent app.

Comment: Right, I wasn't seeing it even when Gmail was opened recently. It turns out it was due to the [Gmail Unread Count Widget](http://alexanderblom.se/gmail-unread-count/)... if I go to gmail using the ordinary app, I see it in my recent app list.

Answer (score 2):

You have to actually open the app from the launcher icon to get it to show up in your recent apps.  Another case of it not showing up is when you access it via the notification bar when you click on your email notifications.