# Why "Messages" app is never seen in the app list?

Tags: recents-screen, google-messages

This has been puzzling me for years. Why it is impossible to switch back to [*Messages* app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging) from any other app using app list?

Two scenarios:

1. *Messages* is **an active one**. I press the three dash app list button and I **can see it** in the list.  I can *switch from that app* to some other one.
2. I did what in above, *Messages* app is now **in the background**. When I press the app list button, **it is not listed there**. I cannot *switch to that app* from any other.

I don't know like others, but for me this is very iritatting. Whenever I need to do something in another app (i.e. copy some contact details that I want to post via SMS), when I want to get back to *Messages*, I always must:

- press *Home*
- find *Messages* app's icon:

  - switch left/right to find the screen where I have *Messages* app icon or
  - open app drawer and swipe left/right to find the correct app pane
- tap that icon to "re-launch" *Messages* app.

What is so special in this app that it does not or cannot appear in the regular app list? I think I can name only this single app that has such a weird behaviour.

I thought that the answer [is in here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/1136/20449) that it simply behaves as Gmail. But that 2011's answer is no longer valid, because *Gmail* does appear in the app list, while *Messages* are not.

---

**EDIT**: I am using [realme GT 5G](https://www.gsmchoice.com/en/catalogue/realme/gt5g/) with Android <s>12</s> **13** and realme UI 3.0. But, as far as I recall, I have been observing this behaviour on **each and every phone** that I have been using since introduction of *Messages by Google* app in 2014. Including: all my Motorola Motos (E3, E4, G4, Z2), Motorola One, TP-Link Neffos X9 and Xiaomi Redmi 6.

The *Messages by Google* app is seen (among others) in the app list **only** if you press app list button while having it in foreground. Switching to *any other* app and pressing app list button again shows all apps in the background *except* this one.

All my phones were never rooted nor has any custom ROM installed. All of them has been used as they came from the shop, from the beginning till end.

Comment: Google Messages app does stick on the recent app list on Pixel 3a (Android 12) and Galaxy M12 (Android 13), and AFAIK on many other devices. Unfortunately, I don't know why it doesn't behave like that on your phone...

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling/reinstalling the app yet?

Comment: I concur with what @AndrewT. said. I have many devices from different manufactures (with Android 8 to 13), and Google Messages app is listed on the recent apps list on all of them. You need to check your phone. By the way, what phone and Android version are you using?

Comment: Answered by editing the question. This case becomes more and more mystery to me. I can't believe that I had this behaviour for years, on eight different phones and yet it seems that I am the lonely survivor on this planet to have it at all. There's something wrong going on hear either with my eyes or my phones! :|

Comment: I'm now wondering if your devices are rooted and/or if some settings related to background apps/recent apps are modified... I don't know which since I just tried no "Background process limit" and "Don't keep activities" on the Developer options, but despite it killed the app, it's still shown on the recent app list....

Comment: No, no root or custom ROM. But this question becomes a guessing-game which is not allowed in here. I was more than sure that this works the way it was described for everyone. My intention was to ask "why", but the whole thing turned to "if". Seems not-reproducible and the question must be closed or deleted.

Comment: Try `Clear Data` and `Clear Cache` from **Settings -> Apps -> Messages -> Storage**.  This fixes all sorts of strange problems

Comment: @RohitGupta To my extreme surprise this has truly solve this problem. However, these are steps that I should undertake **before** asking. So I believe turning your comment into answer might not be an option.

Comment: @RohitGupta This problem ("missing" Messages app in recent app list) seems to be returning either after a while or after next system update. I am still stick with realme GT 5G, but my system was updated to Android 13 and the problem has returned. Again, clearing the data and cache has resolved the issue. So I think you should post this as an answer.